# How can I simplify or loop excel vba code for data exchange in different sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making calculation form where you can enter element quantity and select materials from drop down list on sheet1 (all info will go to the sheet2) and in sheet2 you can change same materials that were set in sheet1 to other from drop down list and it automatically update info in sheet1. I have the code that works perfectly(see code below) and it works both ways.
Question is that the code for checking and changing the values is ok with me but it has to to be repeated for about 10 different positions(ranges) that are defined next to 51 different element calculations and it need to be entered 1000+ times. If there is possibility to somehow group that 10 position with one code similar to "loop"   then it would be repeated just for 100+ times :)

the idea is to be able to adjust "materials"in both sheets see picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka3bk.jpg)

Main code is in sheet and yes it is _change

calculation sheet (sheet1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call FloorElementExchange1
End Sub
```

main sheet(sheet2)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call FloorElementExchange2
End Sub
```

and all another code that actually do the check and replacement of value is in module (sub  FloorElementExchange1()) that goes like this:

```
sub FloorElementExchange1()

    If Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N67") <> Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F44") Then
        Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F44").Value = Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N67").Value
    End If

sub FloorElementExchange2()

    If Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F44") <> Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N67") Then
        Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N67").Value = Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F44").Value
    End If
```

Comment: Exactly how are you calling this code?

Comment: `If A <> B Then A = B`: Easier to just go `A=B` and forget the check, because that is what you end up with anyway.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not sure what the name for this code is. I found it online, checked it and since it worked for what I was seeking I started to use it. But because I am new to all VBA coding I try not to mess a lot with the codes.

Comment: @AndriusRamaškevičius maybe try [without check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57215955/11167163)

Comment: @AJD if I remove the check part from both sheets then for some reasons it kills excel. If I write the same code but only for one sheet then its ok. I'm not sure is that somehow correspond with code check line but it seems to me that it does.

Comment: I meant how are you *running* this code?  In an event handler?

Comment: My guess is that both are in a `_Change` event and setting itself up to be an eternal loop.  `.EnableEvents=False` at some point will cure this. But, without seeing the code and how it is run/called it is hard to tell. (@TimWilliams)

Comment: A single update procedure, driven from a hidden worksheet which maps cells from one sheet to the other, with a "direction" parameter would work.  If the OP can provide more details...

Comment: @AJD. I have edited the question. And yes it is in sheet code as _Change that call a sub in module with specific code for the exact sheet.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try , your `If` condition isn't needed here

Sheet1 :

```
Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F15").Value = Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N17").Value
```

Sheet2 :

```
Worksheets("CALCULATION").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("main sheet").Range("F15").Value
```

**Note** : Your check is useless and waste time .. Try without this will be quite faster

Comment: If I remove the check part from both sheets then for some reasons it kills excel. If I write the same code but only for one sheet then its ok. I'm not sure is that somehow correspond with code check line but it seems to me that it does.

Comment: @AndriusRamaškevičius can you edit your issue and add all your code please ?

Comment: I have edited the question maybe it is what you mean by all code.

Comment: Are all these sub in the same module ? @AndriusRamaškevičius

Comment: each sub has its own module

Comment: @AndriusRamaškevičius If this answer answered to your need May I ask you to accept this answer  ?