# VBA Excel autoincrement value on the following sheet, when changing data on active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have my values incremented on the following sheet by 1 after the code execution on the activesheet.

The situation looks like this:
        Public Sub ResizeCiv2()

```
   Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
   Dim targetRange As Range
   Dim targetShape As Shape


' Define the sheet that has the pictures
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' Define the range the images is going to fit
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("C3:K24")

' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes
    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

   Next targetShape

   Call CivBox
   Call Divider

   ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")
   With Sheets("Cables 1").Range("C50:C51")
   .Value = .Value + 1
   End With

  End Sub
```

And now debugger highlights  `.Value = .Value + 1` saying, that it's type mismatch.

[image]

This is my active sheet with one picture.
As per the code above, I am going to add up another picture occasionally. If so, I need the value incrementation by 1 on the following sheet...

[image]

If I cannot do it  nether  with the `With` statement nor with `Sheet("Cables 1").Range("C50").Value = Range("C50").Value + 1` is there any option to make it running?

It's possibly related to this query:
[How can I simplify or loop excel vba code for data exchange in different sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214197/how-can-i-simplify-or-loop-excel-vba-code-for-data-exchange-in-different-sheets)

**UPDATE:**

I found some solution here:

[Increment Cell Values in a Range by 1 with VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521576/increment-cell-values-in-a-range-by-1-with-vba-excel)

and tried with my code...

```
Public Sub ResizeCiv2()

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetShape As Shape
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("Cables 1").Range("C50:C51")

' Define the sheet that has the pictures
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' Define the range the images is going to fit
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("C3:K24")

' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes
    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

Next targetShape

Call CivBox
Call Divider

ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")

Dim myCell As Range
With rng
myCell = myCell + 1
End With

 End Sub
```

Now, the debugger says:
**Object variable or With variable not set**

When I superseede the myCell line with `Value = .Value + 1`, then I am getting error:
**Type mismatch**

Comment: ```With Sheets("Cables 1").Range("C50:C51")``` is two cells, you can only modify the value of a single cell without using an array.

Comment: @Warcupine, actually you can modify the value of multiple cell range without an array (see my answer)

Comment: @HTH Isn't that an array within the range object?

Comment: @Warcupine, it's a `Range` reference. While `.Range("C50:C51").Value` would be an array

Comment: @hth But wouldn't pastespecial need to access that array in order to do its thing.

Comment: @Warcupine, don't we play around too much with that. Almost everything in Excel ends up using arrays under the hood. The point was if it was possibile to update the value of a multple cells range without the explicit use of an array. Or at least that's what I intended was the point.

Comment: @HTH I don't think the OP was against arrays, I was just pointing out they were trying to  assign a single value to a multi-cell range and that was why it was failing. You said it can be done, I asked for clarification as it seemed like what you were doing was using an array and obfuscating it within an object. Was just curious is all.

Comment: @Warcupine, I don't think OP was against array, too (and I can't imagine why you mentioned that). Indeed, they were trying to assign a single value to a multi-cell range and they were failing. But, indeed, as per your vision, they were _using arrays_ also,   and I said that it can be done using the same object they used. They weren't _obfuscating_ anything and neither was I

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210679/discussion-between-warcupine-and-hth).

Answer (score 0):

the more obvious solution would be looping through cells

but you could play with a `PasteSpecial` option to add values to cells:

```
With Sheets("Cables 1")
    .Range("A1").Copy '<-- change A1 to whatever cell address you'd use to store increment value
    .Range("C50:C51").PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

where I stored the value of the wanted increment in cell "A1", but you can change it both in cell address and increment

Comment: I don't need the pastespecial value. I need the value incrementation to these columns.

Comment: No mate, unfortunately not, because I think that it doesn't make sense, since you are referring me to range ("A1"). However thank you for your help :)

Comment: if you tried you'd find out it does excactly what you need. And that range A1 can be set wherever you want: you may want to use some A1000 or whatever row index ensuring it'll never touch your actual data

Comment: I will try it by the next occasion. Now I have got the solution for this. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem here:

[How do I Increase cell value in Excel using VBA? Error: Type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935693/how-do-i-increase-cell-value-in-excel-using-vba-error-type-mismatch)

so my code should look like this:

```
Public Sub ResizeCiv2()

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetRange As Range
Dim targetShape As Shape

Set rng = Sheets("Cables 1").Range("C50:C51")

' Define the sheet that has the pictures
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
' Define the range the images is going to fit
Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("C3:K24")

' Loop through each Shape in Sheet
For Each targetShape In targetSheet.Shapes
    ' Check "picture" word in name
    If targetShape.Name Like "*Picture*" Then
        ' Call the resize function
        SizeToRange targetShape, targetRange
    End If

Next targetShape

Call CivBox
Call Divider

ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value = Range("D52")
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(50, 3).Value + 1
Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value = Sheets("Cables 1").Cells(51, 3).Value + 1

End sub
```

Where instead of "range" I am specifying the certains cells in the sheet.